# how to use optional chaining with map operator?

Tags: node.js, optional-chaining

I have a scenario where I am reading a yaml file and based upon the data, make calls to tag aws resources.

```
await Promise.all(doc?.SQS.map(async (queue)=>{
  // code to tag 1 queue
}))
```

Now the yaml file may not have a any sqs, in which case `doc?.SQS` returns undefined as expected. How can I make the map to not run in this scenario ? I tried below but it didn't work as expected.

```
await Promise.all(doc?.SQS?.map?.(async (queue)=>{
  // code to tag 1 queue
}))
```

.

```
await Promise.all(doc?.SQS && doc?.SQS?.map(async (queue)=>{
  // code to tag 1 queue
}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`doc?.SQS?.map()` won't run if either `doc` or `SQS` is `undefined` or `null`. That's the purpose of conditional chaining.

The problem is, that `Promise.all` expects an iterable. But if `doc.SQS` is not defined `doc?.SQS?.map(...)` results in `undefined`, which is not iterable. Thus `Promise.all` throws an error.

So you can either check before calling `Promise.all`

```
if (doc?.SQS) {
  await Promise.all(doc.SQS.map(...))
}
```

or you can ensure, that `Promise.all` always receives an iterable -- even if it's just an empty array

```
await Promise.all(doc?.SQS?.map(...) || []);
```

or

```
await Promise.all((doc?.SQS? || []).map(...));
```

I personally would opt for the first way, because it seems much more readable, especially if the callback of `map` is more than a oneliner ...

Comment: thanks. I figured later that doc?.SQS && await Promise.all(doc.SQS.map(...) works as well. But your approach seems much cleaner.